# Can I have/use different Versions of rails in the same machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am actually reading a rails book that is written for rails 2.3.5. I want to test Rails 3 beta as well. Is it possible to have such a setup in my Mac OS leopard?

I have tried with gem list -d rails. There are many versions stored in my mac but I don't know how to use different versions of rails while creating applications using rails command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While RVM is great there's no need for it in this use-case.

Install the Rails 3 gem: **gem install rails—pre**

Create new project: **rails project_name**      (this will use the latest version installed)

To create projects with a specific version: **rails _2.3.5_ project_name**

Comment: rails--pre is the pre-release version of Rails 3.

Comment: Do note that that it's actually "rails _ 2.3.5 _ project_name"  (without the spaces between the version number and the underscores). StackOverflow formatted the original.

Answer (score 4):

Yes! Try [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). It is awesome, you can have many different versions of Ruby, and for each one you can have different versions of gems. And you can run the same tests on all those versions. Isn't that cool?!

Quick How-To:

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.8.7 --default
$ gem install rails -v 1.0.0
$ rvm gemset create rails238
$ rvm 1.8.7@rails238
$ gem install rails -v 2.3.8
```

Now,

```
$ rvm 1.8.7
```

will give you ruby 1.8.7 and rails 1.0

And,

```
$ rvm 1.8.7@rails238
```

will give you ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8

You can make 2.3.8 as default one with

```
$ rvm use 1.8.7@rails238 --default
```

BTW rvm is documented really good.

Comment: I need to have Rails 1.0 and Rails 2.3.8 (the latest stable version) in my mac. And I have to use 1.0 for some projects and 2.3.8 for others... Can i Do it without installing a huge separate stack of ruby environment ?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this anymore is to use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/), the Ruby Version Manager, which isolates different Ruby environments from each other.

A coworker of mine did a blog entry on [setting up Rails 3 and RVM (and Ruby 1.9)](http://codequietly.com/2010/5/rvm-ruby-1-9-and-rails-3-you-complete-me), which you might find interesting.