# Can start new rails 3.2 project after installing rails 4 beta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I installed rails 4 beta1 to try out. now, I am trying to create a new `rails 3.2` app using [rails version hack](http://www.42.mach7x.com/2010/10/03/create-a-rails-app-in-a-specific-version/) but it doesn't work.

```
$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (4.0.0.beta1, 3.2.13, 3.1.0)

$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0.beta1

$ rails _3.2.13_ demo
/home/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:317:in `bin_path': can't find gem rails (["3.2.13"]) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /home/gaurish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/gaurish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/gaurish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'

$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-02-24 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/gaurish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/gaurish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/gaurish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
     - /home/gaurish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => 1
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --verbose"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

what is wrong, how do I fix this so I can have both rails 4 & rails 3.2 installed at the same time?

Comment: Did this no work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034875/can-i-have-use-different-versions-of-rails-in-the-same-machine

Comment: Nope. Only solution I found till now is put rails 4 in its own gemset via rvm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update your rubygems to 2.0.3

```
gem update --system
```

and don't panic! It's just Rails 3

```
rails _3.2.13_ new demo
```

Comment: I needed to run `gem install rails -v 3.2.13` before running `rails _3.2.13_ new demo`

Comment: How in the world did you find this out? "rails --help" doesn't describe this syntax. (Grrr... every day, an undocumented feature.)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem earlier today.

Removing rails 4.0.0.beta1 and reinstalling it, then using `rails _3.2.13__` as stated in your question solved the issue for me.

Comment: Well, maybe your global gemset is screwed, I'd try rvm implode (destroys rvm) and reinstall, but that may be extremist.

Comment: removing rails (gem uninstall rails) and then re-adding only the version I wanted worked for me. Maybe the important part was simply reinstalling